# To print a list of words (vector<string>) using pointers

Tags: c++, string, pointers, vector

I am trying to print the list of words from a vector of string (query_list) but I can't get it to work. I know that the current code prints the address.

```
        vector<string>* query_list_ptr;
        query_list_ptr = &query_list;

        for (i = 0; i < num_words; i++) {
            cout << query_list_ptr << " ";
            query_list_ptr++;
        }
```

I tried the following:

1. I get an error when I tried using "*query_list_ptr" to dereference it at the "cout <<" line.
2. I also get an error when I tried variations of "vector<string>* query_list_ptr" to  "vector<string*> query_list_ptr".
3. Another error is "query_list_ptr = query_list" that's why I ended up adding the ampersand to "query_list_ptr = &query_list;".

Thanks for all the help. I could do without pointers but it's for my CS class about pointers.

Comment: Why not simply print words from the vector like `for(const auto& word : query_list) cout << word << ' ';`?

Comment: You have a collection of strings, not a collection of vectors. So you need a pointer to string, not a pointer to vector, to go over that collection (if you insist on using pointers at all).

Comment: `query_list_ptr` is a pointer to a vector. `*query_list_ptr` is a vector. What _exactly_ is the assignment you're supposed to be doing? I strongly doubt that a `vector<string>*` is the answer to it.

Comment: @MikeCAT I went through my textbook and your solution is not even close to what I was following. I thought constants are to be initialized and declared prior to compilation. (I feel so lost, but I'll keep on chuggin') Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The pointer to the first element of `std::vector` can be obtained via the [`data()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) member function.

```
const string* query_list_ptr; // you want to print words, so I guess the pointer should point to string
query_list_ptr = query_list.data(); // get the pointer to the first element

for (i = 0; i < num_words; i++) {
    cout << *query_list_ptr << " "; // dereference the pointer to get the word to print
    query_list_ptr++;
}
```